# autofs nfs mount Redhat share from Ubuntu client - showmount reports "RPC: Program/version mismatch"

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, nfs, autofs

Trying to use autofs to mount an export on my Fedora 11 workstation (xulu) from a laptop running Ubuntu 9 -

but showmount runs into an annoying error -

```
sbeam@clammy$ sudo showmount -e xulu
rpc mount export: RPC: Program/version mismatch; low version = 3, high version = 3
```

*but* I can actually mount the NFS dir just fine with normal 'mount' command.

On the server, /etc/sysconfig/nfs contains the default, but enabling NFS V2 only results in the mismatch changing from 3/3 to 3/2

```
MOUNTD_NFS_V1="no"
MOUNTD_NFS_V2="no"
MOUNTD_NFS_V3="yes"
```

so any ideas how to resolve this "mismatch"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try commenting out all the mountd lines in /etc/sysconfig/nfs and restarting NFS on your Fedora machine.

Apparently showmount has issues if only specific versions of the mount protocol are enabled.

To force a specific NFS version, I'd use -o vers=X on the client rather than messing with the server.

Comment: that did it, thanks for sharing. cheers ~~